# Не отображается количество перестановок и обменов(с++)

Tags: c++, сортировка

Имеется небольшая программа по сортировке массива 2-мя методами(выбором и обмена),вывод и сортировка выводятся успешно, но количество перестановок и обменов не выводит(точнее выводит, но выводит "0"),пытался отображать их как глобальные, но не помогает,можно ли обойтись БЕЗ УКАЗАТЕЛЕЙ.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
int SortVibor(int[], int,int,int);
int SortObmen(int[], int,int,int); 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int V;
        cout<<"Введите номер варианта"<<endl;
        cin>>V;
    int size = 50+2*V; //размер массива
    int array[size] = {};
    int array2[size]= {};//создаем еще один массив, чтобы обе функции использовали один и тот же массив
    //заполним массивы случайными числами от 1 до 100
srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 1 + rand() % 100;
        array2[i] = array[i];//копируем значения первого массива во второй, чтобы использовать его в другой функции 
    }
    //выводим неотсортированный массив на экран
    cout << "Неотсортированный массив: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout <<array[i]<<" ";
    } 
    cout << endl << endl;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////выводим отсортированный массив (выбором) на экран
    int count_2compare=0;
    int count_2switch = 0;
    SortVibor(array,size,count_2compare,count_2switch);
    cout << "Отсортированный массив (выбором): " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout <<array[i]<<" ";
    } 
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Количество сравнений"<<" "<<count_2compare<<endl;
    cout<<"Количество обменов"<<" "<<count_2switch<<endl;;
    cout << endl << endl;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////выводим отсортированный массив (обмена) на экран
    int count_compare = 0;
    int count_switch = 0;
    SortObmen(array2,size,count_compare,count_switch);
    cout << "Отсортированный массив (обменом): " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout <<array2[i]<<" ";
    } 
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Количество сравнений"<<" "<<count_compare<<endl;
    cout<<"Количество обменов"<<" "<<count_switch<<endl;;
    cout << endl << endl;
return 0;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int SortVibor(int array[], int size,int count_2compare,int count_2switch)
{
int min;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) // i - номер текущего шага
    { 
        int pos = i; 
        min = array[i];
        count_2compare+=1;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < size; ++j) // цикл выбора наименьшего элемента
        {
            if (array[j] < min) 
           {
               pos = j; 
               min = array[j]; 
               count_2switch+=1;
           }
            count_2compare+=1;
        }
        array[pos] = array[i]; 
        array[i] = min; // меняем местами наименьший с array[i]
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int SortObmen(int array2[], int size, int count_compare,int count_switch)
{
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) // i - номер прохода
    {            
        count_compare+=1;
        for(int j = 0; j < size - 1; ++j) // внутренний цикл прохода
        {     
            if (array2[j + 1] < array2[j]) 
            {
                temp = array2[j + 1]; 
                array2[j + 1] = array2[j]; 
                array2[j] = temp;
                count_switch+=1;
            }
            count_compare+=1;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно и без указателей, раз у вас C++. Передавайте счетчики по ссылке, например, так:

```
int SortVibor(int array[], int size,int& count_2compare,int& count_2switch);
```

Без этого вы работаете с **копиями** счетчиков.

Disclaimer для нервных :) - ответил только на заданный вопрос, правильность кода сортировки и т.п. не проверял.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Если ответ устраивает - помечайте как принятый...